# What happens to the pregnant woman's baby in the first episode of Death Parade?

Tags: death-parade

In the first episode of Death Parade, after the first game, the woman's soul is voided, and the man gets reincarnated.

[image: Outcome first episode]

During the darts game, the woman tells the man that she is pregnant. Does this mean that the baby's soul is also voided? This would be weird knowing that the baby probably was reincarnated not so long ago and had no impact on what his or her mother would do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I imagine that in the Death Parade universe this happens often enough to have a specific arbiter rule about it. Any details of such a rule haven't been revealed yet however.

It is the woman and the man's souls that are being judged in that trial, so I presume the baby either

- Has a separate case for review, possibly not present in the woman's body in body/soul during the woman's trial
- Is not eligible for trial due to not having enough life experience.

The Rebirth/Void concept that Death Parade uses is based on Buddhist concepts, which means that an opinion-based answer could be highly debatable as it would be based on theological concepts such as the possibility of humans being born malicious, or becoming malicious through life's influence.

**References if you want to decide by yourself:**

[Reincarnation: The Process of Rebirth](http://www.fst.org/reinc3.htm)

[Forum Debate](http://forums.plentyoffish.com/datingPosts10265049.aspx)

Comment: On a side note, that would have been a very strange episode if it was a separate trial